# Loading a JSON file with jQuery.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a newbie in JS and I am trying to do something very simple.

I have a JSON file named "data.json" and I want to load it, so, I do this:

```
$.getJSON("data.json",function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

And then I pass that loaded JSON to a function in library that does this:

```
$("#example1").handsontable({
    data:data,     //<--- error here
    minRows: 2,
    minCols: 3,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    currentRowClassName: 'currentRow',
    currentColClassName: 'currentCol',
    autoWrapRow: true,
    colHeaders: true
});

$("#example1").handsontable('selectCell', 3, 3);
```

Firebug says

```
ReferenceError: data is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

data:data,
```

I thought I already loaded the JSON into the `data` variable? Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you have a `data:data`? Remove it and I think it will work.

Comment: I don't see where you are doing anything other than logging the data received by `getJSON` request.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call from a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call-from-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` is only defined inside the callback you pass to `getJSON`.  Whatever you're ever going to do with that has to be done within that function.

So instead of (or in addition to) the `console.log(data)`, you need to do the `handsontable` call (or call a function that does the `handsontable` call) right there in the getJSON callback.

Also, `getJSON` is asynchronous, which means even if you do something like assign `data` to a global variable inside the callback, that variable probably won't have that value yet when you get to the next line of code after the `getJSON` call.  All you've done is issued a request - "hey, go get this JSON object, and when you finish doing that, call this function. Meanwhile, I'm going to go on about my business. Thanks!"

Comment: Thanks for responding.. Is there a way to just read the json data from a file and assign it to a variable. But thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Alternatively assign data to a variable with scope outside the callback. Either way, it has to be done inside that callback.

Comment: @kinakuta- but if you do that, then you still have to make sure that whatever uses that variable doesn't get triggered until the callback has been . . . called . . . back.